# check UserRole and send to unique home url

Tags: meteor

When users log into their account I would like to check the users role and direct them to a suitable home page. Roles is set by `meteor-roles` and I'm using `flow-router`. Currently this just throws a trigger error:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
```

Is it even possible to access `roles` in the router file?

Path: `Routes.js`

```
FlowRouter.route("/", {
  name: 'home',
  action: function() {
    var user = Meteor.user();
    var userRole = user.roles;

    if (userRole == 'is_student') {
      FlowRouter.go('profileNew');
    } else if (userRole == 'is_teacher') {
      FlowRouter.go('profile');    
    } else {
      FlowRouter.go('profileAdmin');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

var user = Meteor.user(); // You are not login because app is just started

var userRole = user.roles; //user is undefined at this moment so how can you get the roles? That why its throwing the error.

So you can manage this situlation like this:-

```
FlowRouter.route("/", {
  name: 'home',
  action: function() {
    var user = Meteor.user();
    if(user){
       var userRole = user.roles;
       if (userRole == 'is_student') {
           FlowRouter.go('profileNew');
       } else if (userRole == 'is_teacher') {
           FlowRouter.go('profile');    
       } else {
          FlowRouter.go('profileAdmin');
       }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This just leads to a blank page with no errors.

Comment: I think this is what you looking for: https://medium.com/@satyavh/using-flow-router-for-authentication-ba7bb2644f42#.pzuepjg83